# Performance with nested functions in C#

Tags: c#, performance, function, nested

Which of the following code snippets would cause the least amount of overhead (or would the IL be the same)? My program could potentially generate huge jagged arrays, depending on the number of Constraint Formulas I feed it. I want to limit the unnecessary allocation of memory for the decimal[][] objects:

```
decimal[][] originalFormTableau = CreateOriginalFormTableau();
decimal[][] standardFormTableau = InsertSlackVariables(originalFormTableau);
this.Engine = new SimplexEngine(standardFormTableau, normalizationThreshold);
```

or

```
this.Engine = new SimplexEngine(
    InsertSlackVariables(
    CreateOriginalFormTableau()),
    normalizationThreshold);
```

or any other suggestion (maybe use using ref instead?)

Comment: If you really have to think these kind of micro optimizations, you are in trouble.

Comment: Why? I know early optimization is evil, and I'm not experiencing any visible performance issues, but I do prefer to do things the right way. Are you actually able to answer my question, sir?

Comment: Early optimisation isn't evil, only premature - that is, **too** early. Of course, knowing the answer to questions like this is one of the things that helps us judge whether something is worth doing always, never, or when profiling indicates it's needed. (Also, Knuth only said that to head off gripes about optimisation while he was in the middle of explaining how to optimise a given piece of code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break them down:

```
//we start with a space on the stack from a local or parameter
//holding whatever normalizationThreshold is
//1. Create a space on the stack to hold a decimal[][]
//Call CreateOriginalFormTableau() method
//assign result to that space.
decimal[][] originalFormTableau = CreateOriginalFormTableau();
//2. Create a space on the stack to hold a decimal[][]
//Call InsertSlackVariables() method, passing in the first decimal[][]
//assign result to that second space.
decimal[][] standardFormTableau = InsertSlackVariables(originalFormTableau);
//3. Call the Engine setter with the second space or assign it to the Engine field.
this.Engine = new SimplexEngine(standardFormTableau, normalizationThreshold)
```

VS:

```
//we start with a space on the stack from a local or parameter
//holding whatever normalizationThreshold is
//1. Create a space on the stack to hold a decimal[][]
//Call CreateOriginalFormTableau() method
//assign result to that space.
//2. Create a space on the stack to hold a decimal[][]
//Call InsertSlackVariables() method, passing in the first decimal[][]
//assign result to that second space.
//3. Call the Engine setter with the second space or assign it to the Engine field.
this.Engine = new SimplexEngine(
  InsertSlackVariables(
  CreateOriginalFormTableau()),
  normalizationThreshold);
```

They're exactly the same code, but one version gives a name to what another leaves unnamed.

They might have slightly different performance in debug builds, though even there I'd doubt it (some of the times where release builds reuses stack slots, debug builds don't, so you are able to examine in-scope variable even after they won't be used again, but most likely it won't reuse the unnamed slots either, and even if it did make a difference the impact would be minute).

Comment: Thanks Jon! Interesting info regarding debug vs rebuild.

Comment: @Heliac the practical difference of that behaviour, is that in debug builds mostly objects can't be collected while a local reference is in scope. In release builds they can as soon as the last time the local is used. Throws up some surprises when `Timer`s get collected while in scope.

Answer (score 3):

Did the test, for science:

**Version 1**

```
public void Test1()
{
    decimal[][] originalFormTableau = CreateOriginalFormTableau();
    decimal[][] standardFormTableau = InsertSlackVariables(originalFormTableau);
    this.Engine = new SimplexEngine(standardFormTableau, normalizationThreshold);
}
```

Outputs:

```
.method public hidebysig instance void Test1() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][] originalFormTableau,
        [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][] standardFormTableau)
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: call instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][] ConsoleApplication2.Class2::CreateOriginalFormTableau()
    L_0006: stloc.0 
    L_0007: ldarg.0 
    L_0008: ldloc.0 
    L_0009: call instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][] ConsoleApplication2.Class2::InsertSlackVariables(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][])
    L_000e: stloc.1 
    L_000f: ldarg.0 
    L_0010: ldloc.1 
    L_0011: ldarg.0 
    L_0012: call instance object ConsoleApplication2.Class2::get_normalizationThreshold()
    L_0017: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication2.SimplexEngine::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][], object)
    L_001c: call instance void ConsoleApplication2.Class2::set_Engine(class ConsoleApplication2.SimplexEngine)
    L_0021: ret 
}
```

**Version 2**

```
this.Engine = new SimplexEngine(
    InsertSlackVariables(
    CreateOriginalFormTableau()),
    normalizationThreshold);
```

Outputs:

```
.method public hidebysig instance void Test2() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: ldarg.0 
    L_0003: call instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][] ConsoleApplication2.Class2::CreateOriginalFormTableau()
    L_0008: call instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][] ConsoleApplication2.Class2::InsertSlackVariables(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][])
    L_000d: ldarg.0 
    L_000e: call instance object ConsoleApplication2.Class2::get_normalizationThreshold()
    L_0013: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication2.SimplexEngine::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal[][], object)
    L_0018: call instance void ConsoleApplication2.Class2::set_Engine(class ConsoleApplication2.SimplexEngine)
    L_001d: ret 
}
```

Compiled in release, optimizations turned on. I have to say, since the local variables aren't reused in the method, I believed the compiler would rewrite `Test1` to look like `Test2`. Somehow, it didn't. So I guess `Test2` would be slightly faster, though it's probably not in a measurable way.

So, unless you're searching for microsecond optimizations, go for the most readable one.

Comment: +1 But note that the jitted code could be even more similar than these near-identical IL.

Comment: Interesting thing I've just noticed, is that while these are very close, and the jitted could be even more similar, as I said, here though the second case comes just in under the size that is eligible for inlining and the first is just one byte too large. Now, those rules aren't standardised and may even be changed already, but still, while I stand by saying it will generally make no real difference, here that generally-negligible difference will just hit on either side of a threshold that could cause some.